# Using pre-trained word embeddings in a keras model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I was following this [`github`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py) code from keras team on how to use pre-trained word embeddings. I was able to understand most of it but I've a doubt regarding vector sizes. I was hoping someone could help me out.

First we define `Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NUM_WORDS)`

Accoding to keras docs for`Tokenizer()` ***num_words*** argument only consider `MAX_NUM_WORDS - 1` so if `MAX_NUM_WORDS=20000` I'll have around `19999` words.

> **num_words**: the maximum number of words to keep, based on word
>   frequency. Only the most common num_words-1 words will be kept.

Next in the code we prepare a `Embedding Matrix` based on glove vectors. When doing that we are considering an matrix of size (20001, 100)`np.zeros((MAX_NUM_WORDS+1, 100))`. I couldn't get why we are consider  a matrix of `20001` if we have only `19999` words in our vocabulary.

Also then we are passing `num_words` to the Embedding layer. According to Embedding layer docs for input_dim argument, It says,

> **input_dim**: int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index
>   + 1.

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=num_words,
                            output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
trainable=False)
```

Here our vocabulary size will be `19999` according to `Tokenizer()` function right? So why are we passing `20001` as `input_dim`

Here's a small snippet of the code taken from that github link.

```
MAX_NUM_WORDS = 20000
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 1000
EMBEDDING_DIR = 100

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NUM_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)

data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

# prepare embedding matrix
num_words = MAX_NUM_WORDS + 1
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i > MAX_NUM_WORDS:
        continue
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your doubt is valid. The change was made in [this commit](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/630a3a877c3c96ce39be7b0611570466c8c9f447#diff-9b029e798566d6f8d5a6e596d15691af) of the code to keep the word with `index = MAX_NUM_WORDS`. Before that there was a [commit](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/commit/65e5632013ff5bf98c76548565037f7745757537#diff-25002d783a7458a5113a2a3807523c30) on `Tokenizer` to make it keep `num_words` words instead of `num_words - 1` words. But this change of `Tokenizer` was [reverted](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/commit/65e5632013ff5bf98c76548565037f7745757537#diff-25002d783a7458a5113a2a3807523c30) afterwards. So I guess the author of the example update might have assumed that `Tokenizer` kept `num_words` words when the update was committed.

Answer (score 1):

For the embedding, input dim (num_words in the below code) is the size of the vocabulary. For example, if your data is integer encoded to values between 0-10, then the size of the vocabulary would be 11 words. That is the reason 1 is added to the min of len(word_index) and MAX_NUM_WORDS.

Embedding matrix will have the the dimension of vocabulary size and vector length

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)

num_words = min(MAX_NUM_WORDS, len(word_index)) + 1
```

Have created a simple tokenizer to explain this.

```
t  = Tokenizer(num_words=5)
fit_text = ["The earth is an awesome place live"]
t.fit_on_texts(fit_text)
word_index = t.word_index
​
print('word_index : ',word_index)
print('len word_index : ',len(t.word_index))
word_index :  {'the': 1, 'earth': 2, 'is': 3, 'an': 4, 'awesome': 5, 'place': 6, 'live': 7}
len word_index :  7
```

In the below case, you are covering a vocabulary of size 4 only because tokenizer indexing starts from 1.

```
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((5, 10))
embedding_matrix
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i < 5:       
        embedding_matrix[i] = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

print (embedding_matrix)
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

In the below case, you need to add 1 (5+1) to cover the vocabulary of size 5 to cover for the index 0

```
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((6, 10))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i < 6:       
        embedding_matrix[i] = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

print (embedding_matrix)

[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: I didn't get what you meant? See the code I've posted above. I am considering `MAX_NUM_WORDS=20000` then I passed it to `Tokenizer()`. According to tokenizer docs `MAX_NUM_WORDS-1` words will be kept right? So then why am I adding  + 1 when building the embedding matrix is my question? Here my vocabulary size will be 19,999 right??

Comment: You are right, tokenizer keeps (numwords-1). But the indexing will start from 1.  

when you create an embedding matrix, you need to add 1 to the vocabulary size so as to cover for the index 0.

Comment: I just added a sample code to explain embedding_matrix.

Comment: That's exactly my doubt. As per tokenizer we have only 4 words right? Then why do we need to cover for the vocabulary size of 5? Shouldn't we build embedding matrix to cover for vocabulary size of 4? That's what confusing me a lot.

Comment: Excuse me, when i use len(word_index) + 1 , i got 'Layer weight shape (9, 128) not compatible with provided weight shape (8, 128)' , it means i need to add another vector of my zero index to my  embedding matrix right ?

Comment: i already have embedding matrix obtained from word2vec.